# matrix powers problem

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

let $ A $ be the matrix :\begin{bmatrix}1 & 3 & 1\\4 & 2 & 3\\2 & 1 & 1  \end{bmatrix}

Prove that $A$ verifies the expression :

$ -A^{3}+4A^{2}+12A+5 I_{3} = O_{3}$

Deduct that $A$ is invertible n calculate it . really need some hints

Comment: compute characteristic polynomial.

Comment: And to add to Troy Woo's hint, you may use [Sarrus' rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus) to compute the  $3\times3$ determinant.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you can do the calculation:
$$A^3=\{\{77,76,56\},\{120,105,88\},\{56,48,41\}\}\\
A^2=\{\{15,10,11\},\{18,19,13\},\{8,9,6\}\}\\
A=\{\{1,3,1\},\{4,2,3\},\{2,1,1\}\}$$
Then try putting them in given equation.Then premultiply the equation by $A^{-1}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: find the characteristic polynomial by solving $$|A-\lambda I_3|=0,$$ where $$I_3=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0 \\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Now use the  [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) (which says that every square matrix satisfies its own characteristic polynomial) (i.e. replace all the $\lambda$s in the characteristic polynomial with $A$s).

---

For the second part, use the fact that $$-A^{3}+4A^{2}+12
A+5 I_{3} = 0_{3} \iff \color{green}{I_3=\frac{1}{5}\left[A^3-4A^2-12A\right]}.$$

Now what happens to $\color{green}{\text{this}}$ equation if we (pre-)multiply everything by $A^{-1} \quad$?

Comment: thanks, i didn't knew this theorem

Comment: thnx again, I wonder about the deduction part, I am not supposed to calculate the determinant, I think I should replace the $λ$ with $0$ to conclude that the p($λ=0$) (characteristic polynomial) is not null thus $A$ is invertible right ?